# What is the physical significance of the frequency factor in the Arrhenius equation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, rate-equation

As the title says, I am wondering what the physical significance of the frequency/pre-exponential factor in the Arrhenius equation. My idea of it is that:

If the units of $E_a$ are energy per molecule, then the Arrhenius equation can be written

$$k_r=Ae^\frac{-E_a}{k_BT}$$

It is my understanding that, if quantum mechanical effects are not significant, the average kinetic energy of a particle in a system will be $k_BT$; this leads me to interpret the exponential factor as the fraction of particles that possess *at least* $E_a$. I have confirmed this by showing that, in a system in which the available energy levels are separated by a factor $\epsilon$, so that energy levels are $n\epsilon$, with $n=1,2,…$, the fraction of molecules in states with $E$ at least $n_min\epsilon$ is

$$e^\frac{-i_{min}\epsilon}{k_BT}$$

Which is of the same form as

$$e^\frac{-E_a}{k_BT}$$

So: if all of the particles in a system possess sufficient energy to react, then $k_r=A$. If not all of the particles in a system possess sufficient energy to react, then the rate constant is $A$ scaled by the fraction of the particles that *do* have sufficient energy.

Still, the constant itself seems ambiguous to me, and I would like some guidance - and perhaps to be pointed in the direction of some reading. Please correct any erroneous chemistry in this post; I am not doing a chemistry degree *yet*, I am in my first year of A levels.

Comment: Hello PhysPhil. You could start reading about the (1) transition state theory and (2) collision theory (or Lewis theory). Both give physical insight into the parameter $A$ of the Arrhenius equation. I think it would be a good place to start, at least it was introduced to me in physical chemistry classes.

Comment: A as "frequency factor" is quite intuitively the frequency of collisions with the required molecule mutual orientation, regardless of the collision energy. Note that it is a function of T as well.

Comment: Very intuitive. So when $A$ is multiplied by the fraction of particles with sufficient energy to react it returns the frequency of successful collisions. I'm not sure how to close this question, since no one has actually 'answered' it, but this answer and @MetalStorm 's suggestions have given me what I need.